# SecurityException: <<other_package>> from uid xxx not allowed to perform READ_CLIPBOARD when calling setPrimaryClip

Tags: android, clipboardmanager, android-app-ops

I've been getting reports of the following crash

```java
SecurityException: <<other_package>> from uid xxx not allowed to perform READ_CLIPBOARD
```

The crash occurred when a user clicks on a button that copies a text into clipboard as shown below.

```kotlin
val clipboard = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", shareUrl)
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

So my app doesn't try to read anything from clipboard. Really confusing why this error could happen.

Does anyone know how this crash happen and how can I fix this?

**Additional Information**

This crash only happens in Android 9 and Android 10 and not happens easily (only 6 users from 200k monthly active users)

I only saw two <<other_package>> in Crashlytics (one is a Bank app and another is a Music app).

I tried to read the source code of `ClipboardService.java` and `AppOpsManager.java` and found that the crash might came from `noteOp` in `AppOpsManager`.

Here is the stack trace of the crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: <<other_package>> from uid xxx not allowed to perform READ_CLIPBOARD
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2087)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2055)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2003)
       at android.content.IClipboard$Stub$Proxy.setPrimaryClip(IClipboard.java:293)
       at android.content.ClipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(ClipboardManager.java:106)
       at my.package.MyClass.copyToClipboard(MyClass.java:63)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7375)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7336)
       at android.view.View.access$3900(View.java:822)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28214)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7829)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:986)

Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at android.app.AppOpsManager.noteOp(AppOpsManager.java:2568)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService.clipboardAccessAllowed(ClipboardService.java:933)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService.setPrimaryClipInternal(ClipboardService.java:775)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService.setPrimaryClipInternal(ClipboardService.java:710)
    at com.android.server.clipboard.ClipboardService$ClipboardImpl.setPrimaryClip(ClipboardService.java:358)
```

Comment: Reading Clipboard is prohibited after android 10

Comment: @BasilBattikhi My code only calls `ClipboardManager.setPrimaryClip`. Is it possible that other app try to read the clipboard can cause my app to crash?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I can now reproduce this crash on Android 9. I created the first app which add a PrimaryClipChangedListener, leave it running in background. Then I used appops to deny app1 from reading clipboard `cmd appops set <package> READ_CLIPBOARD ignore`. Then I created another app which calls setPrimaryClip. it will crash with the same error. I can't reproduce this crash in Android 10 since the PrimaryClipChangedListener doesn't seem to work in background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can finally reproduce the crash in Android 9. This is what I found...

**Root cause:** When foreground app calls `setPrimaryClipboard`, the `ClipboardService` will broadcast the event to `PrimaryClipChangedListener` (if any) and will also make a call to `AppOpsManager.noteOp` to inform about `READ_CLIPBOARD` operation.

If the listener is not allowed to `READ_CLIPBOARD` (user can disallow by using adb shell command: `cmd appops set <package> READ_CLIPBOARD deny`), `AppOpsManager.noteOp` will throw a `SecurityException` and will crash the foreground app.

Now I'm sure that my code doesn't do anything wrong, but unfortunately I think I have to put `try/catch` around `setPrimaryClip`

Comment: This is pretty nefarious! I've seen the same issue on my app. Is manually changing the config using adb the only way to trigger this? Why would the foreground app crash in this case, it isn't doing anything wrong! If anything, the other app, the one listening should crash